# Importing formulae from template

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I'm creating multiple sheets with the same layout and formulae, used for creating a shift/job-schedule for employees where every employee has his own sheet. But when a formula changes (e.g. a new shift is introduced) I have to adjust the formula 20+ times (every employee individually).

To make it more efficient, I wanted to create a template sheet with formulae, which can be used in every other sheet.

How can I import formulae and let Google Sheets calculate it?

E.g. Some variables are in row 1, the formulae are in the cells B1:E16
How can a formula like `"=sum(A1:E1)"` be imported and calculated? I remember something about using Apps Scripts, but can't recall how.

`Importrange` only imports values, and using text like `sum(A1:E1)` doesn't make it calculate it.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `SUM` you could use `QUERY` like:

```
=QUERY(A1:D1, MasterSheet!A1, 0)
```

and **MasterSheet!A1** cell would be: **`select A+B+C+D label A+B+C+D''`**

---

let the master sheet be:

[image: 0]

cell C10:

```
select Col1+Col2+Col3+Col4+Col5+Col6 label Col1+Col2+Col3+Col4+Col5+Col6''
```

and then you can do simple:

[image: 0]

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(C3:C8); 
 IMPORTRANGE("16wnEPLb_OCBpEFY6OGydwBRSRupiJ3cvGNk1aGHofgQ"; "Sheet 1!C10"); 0)
```

Comment: The formula which has to be imported, is in a different Google Spreadsheet.
Target: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12g9ipnYyXTyGgdHqDE7Pna9th5m-OfgsNKVD5pgL2pM/edit?usp=sharing
Master: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1psX9jUTvwv1KJPMLESDGAzuXSq80Eq9WIuTebgkRsLk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks! But now, things get a bit more complicated. Many formulas are more complicated. Multiple vlookups and references are not uncommon in the "template". 
Isn't there any apps-script which is useful to copy the formula's from one sheet to another (again, a different spreadsheet in google Drive)?